# how to download html to pdf in Django framework

Tags: python, django

I am building an CV maker website, in which i what to add a download feature, that is, when the user select an template, fill the required data(the whole template will be in html form) then how can i add the download feature so that the HTML page will be downloaded into PDF file.

This the first problem,
2. one is, do i need to create a separate form.py for each template, or is their any way that only one form will be applicable for all the templates.

I am working on Django framework.

Comment: There's tons of libraries that can do this, one of the good ones i've used is [this](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/)

Comment: thnak you man..